# How to query csv data in ClickHouse from HDFS with some omitted columns

Tags: clickhouse

I want to create a table with engine=hdfs and copy data into a table with engine=MergeTree.
Here my DDL for hdfs table:

```
CREATE TABLE price_hdfs
(
   product_id String,
   price Decimal(16,2),
   regular_price Decimal(16,2),
   promocode_price Decimal(16,2),
   discount Decimal(16,2),
   saved_at DateTime,
   source String,
   bucket_id UInt64
)
ENGINE=HDFS('hdfs://namenode:9000/wdm/price_20????.csv', 'CSV');
```

But csv files on HDFS do not have all trailing columns on all rows:

```
14694303,3078,5400,,2322,2021-08-03 22:15:31,wdm
9201607,2940,4900,,1960,2021-08-03 22:15:31,wdm
...
9201609,2941,4901,2,1961,2021-08-03 22:15:32,wdm,1234 <- this new field bucket_id
```

I get error when query this table:

```
[2021-12-16 11:47:05] Code: 27. DB::ParsingException: Cannot parse input: expected ',' before: '\n9201607,2940,4900,,1960,2021-08-03 22:15:31,wdm\n19364027,2360,5900,,3540,2021-08-03 22:15:32,wdm\n10147914,498,1899,,1401,2021-08-03 22:15:33,wdm\n12333579,2205,':
[2021-12-16 11:47:05]   Row 1:
[2021-12-16 11:47:05]   Column 0,   name: product_id,      type: String,           parsed text: "14694303"
[2021-12-16 11:47:05]   Column 1,   name: price,           type: Decimal(16, 2),   parsed text: "3078"
[2021-12-16 11:47:05]   Column 2,   name: regular_price,   type: Decimal(16, 2),   parsed text: "5400"
[2021-12-16 11:47:05]   Column 3,   name: promocode_price, type: Decimal(16, 2),   parsed text: <EMPTY>
[2021-12-16 11:47:05]   Column 4,   name: discount,        type: Decimal(16, 2),   parsed text: "2322"
[2021-12-16 11:47:05]   Column 5,   name: saved_at,        type: DateTime,         parsed text: "2021-08-03 22:15:31"
[2021-12-16 11:47:05]   Column 6,   name: source,          type: String,           parsed text: "wdm"
[2021-12-16 11:47:05]   ERROR: Line feed found where delimiter (,) is expected. It's like your file has less columns than expected.
[2021-12-16 11:47:05]   And if your file has the right number of columns, maybe it has unescaped quotes in values.
[2021-12-16 11:47:05]   : While executing ParallelParsingBlockInputFormat: While executing HDFS: (at row 1)
[2021-12-16 11:47:05]   . (CANNOT_PARSE_INPUT_ASSERTION_FAILED) (version 21.11.7.9 (official build))
```

How to replace omitted fields (the last one on the example - bucket_id) with null or 0 when query?

Answer (score 1):

I've used a workaround with Hive+Trino to query data from HDFS and import it to ClickHouse.

```
insert into price SELECT * FROM jdbc(
        'jdbc:trino://trino.server:8080/hive/default',
        'select product_id, ... from price'
    );
```

It requires Hive with metadata conntected to HDFS (I had), Trino connected to HDFS and Hive metadata (I had) and jdbc bridge - https://github.com/ClickHouse/clickhouse-jdbc-bridge with Trino driver.

This way provides method to add `where col is not null` to select query in jdbc or make some columns nullable in destination table in ClickHouse.